# Passing data from one page to another using PHP Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, database, session-cookies

I'm using sessions in PHP. At the top of both pages, I do a session_start(); before anything else.

Later on, information is pulled from a database that is used to populate the page with information. Right now I'm only using 20 different items. The first page iterates through the database and gives me output that I expect. Once you select an image, it goes to another page that should have more information on that object. The problem is, the new page always shows the last object in the database. I'll post relevant code and hope that someone can point out my failure.

```
<?php

//initial page with list of objects

session_start();

$_SESSION['listingID'] = $listingID;


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

</head>
<body>

<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
        <h1><a href="#" target="__blank">Some H1 that works fine</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="__blank">Some link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>



</body>
</html>

<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbservername;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    //echo "Connection is successful!<br/>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
    $users = $dbh->query($sql);



    foreach ($users as $row) {
    extract($row);  
    $_SESSION['listingID'] = $listingID;
    echo "THIS IS listingID ". $listingID;
    echo '<div id="main" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">';
    echo '<article class="thumb">';
    echo '<a href="lake_full.php?'.$listingID.'" class="image"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
    echo "<h2>$address</br>$city, $state $zip</br>$$asking_price</h2>";
    echo '</article>';
    echo '</div>';  



   } // end foreach

$dbh = null;
}
catch (PDOexception $e) {
    echo "Error is: " . $e-> etmessage();
}


?>
```

The following code is what I'm using on the new page that should bring over the 'id' or something associated with the image selected on the first page.

```
 <?php

//lake_full.php
session_start();

$listingID = $_SESSION['listingID'];
echo "ID IS ".$listingID;

?>


    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <h1><a href="#">Some H1</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="__blank" class="icon fa-info-circle">Some Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>



    </body>
    </html>

<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbservername;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    //echo "Connection is successful!<br/>";
    $sql = "SELECT listingID FROM $tablename";
    $users = $dbh->query($sql);

    echo "THIS ID IS ". $mls;

        echo '<div id="main" style="margin-top: 2em;">';
        echo '<article class="thumb">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="image"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
        echo "<h2>$address</br>$city, $state $zip</br>$$asking_price</h2>";
        echo '</article>';
        echo '</div>';

    $dbh = null;
}
catch (PDOexception $e) {
    echo "Error is: " . $e-> etmessage();
}



?>
```

Comment: On your first page, you're setting the session with `$listingID`. Where does that variable come from? And where does all your database variables come from? You also set the session with `$listingID` again, in your try-block?

Comment: I removed all of the mysql stuff so that it wouldn't clutter the code. 

What's happening is I can echo the ID or whatever for the house selected, but when I select it, the new page only reflects the last entry in the database. I'm trying to make it remember which house was selected so I can show all of that information on the next page.

Comment: Do you actually have a whitespace character before `<?php` in the *"new page"*? I also don't see where you're using `$listingID`

Comment: Does `$listIingD` come from the database? Hard to tell where your variables comes from since you're using `extract()`. If it does, you're overwriting the session variable on each iteration so it will always only contain the last.

Comment: There is no whitespace character, it's just how it was copied over to this stack question. 

Each house has an ID and a listing ID. You can see the other variables on the first page in the echoing of the HTML and they work fine. I'm just having an issue trying to store which house was selected so that it is brought up on the new page with the rest of the information. I'm only getting the last house on the database right now no matter the selection.

Comment: ListingID comes from the db.

Comment: You should use query strings to send the ID to `lake_full.php` instead of sessions. Change `"lake_full.php?'.$listingID.'"` to `"lake_full.php?listingID='.$listingID.'"` and get it on the other page with: `$listingID = $_GET['listingID']` (instead of session).

Comment: echo '<a href="lake_full.php?listingID='.$listingID.'" class="image"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' . $image . '" /></a>';


Now it breaks the site and says it's not working.

Comment: The markup looks correct. I just added text inside the string so that can't be the reason for it breaking. How does it break and what does it say exactly?

Comment: I was missing a semi-colon lol. It works great now!! The new page has the proper id in the echo so it works wonders. 

You guys are AWESOME!!!

Comment: I can make it an answer so you can mark this question as answered.

Comment: By all means go ahead and I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently overwriting `$_SESSION['listingID']` on each iteration on your loop, which means that it will always only contain the last item.

Instead of using sessions, you should use query strings.

Change the following row in your first file:

```
echo '<a href="lake_full.php?'.$listingID.'" class="image"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
```

to

```
echo '<a href="lake_full.php?listingID='.$listingID.'" class="image"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
```

Now on `lake_full.php`, instead of using sessions, you can now get the ID using the `$_GET`-super global:

```
if (!isset($_GET['listingID'])) {
    // If we didn't get an ID, we can't continue, so stop the script
    die('Invalid listing ID');
}

$listingID = $_GET['listingID'];

// ... the rest of the code...
```